# Avoid Flash to execute code in a movieclip while a gotoAndStop is trigger [as3 flash 9]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The title is not really explicit but the problem is not very simple to explain in few words.
The bug is simple, I have a timeline with 3 frames :

- frame 1 : gotoAndStop(3);
- frame 2 : a movieclip with a trace inside : trace("test");
- frame 3 : nothing

If I run the export, "test" is displaying in the console and shouldn't because we go from 1 to 3, so the frame 2 and the movieclip are never on the scene.
With Flash 10, I don't have this issue :/

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: Try making frame 1 blank and moving the rest along by one frame.

Comment: Are you sure the `MovieClip` on frame 2 is not also on frame 1 or 3? You say you don't have this issue with "Flash 10", do you mean if you change the Flash Player target version in your publish setting to Flash Player 10 you don't see this behavior with the same file?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet : I notice this issue with another file much more complexe and with a blanc frame at first. So, non, that doesn't change anything

Comment: @Aaron : Yes, if I target Flash Player 10 in the publish setting, the issue disappear, for the same file…

Comment: Interesting. They did change the behavior of `gotoAndStop()` at some point early on (in short, it used to always be asynchronous, they changed it to be synchronous in some cases -- in AS2 it was always synchronous) but I can't seem to find any documentation on that change at the moment. It could be related to what you're seeing.

Comment: how about you add a preloader which will wait until bytesLoaded == bytesTotal -- I've had some very weird problems without it even though I was running the local build which loaded in zero time

Comment: @Andrei Nikolaenko I have a loader like this on the first animation where I noticed this issue :/

Comment: I just tested with 9, 10 and 11 target players, none of them gave me the bug. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: The Flash version I use is CS 5.5.

Comment: Works well for me in Flash CC 2014 publishing to FP 10.3 and FP 16.